# Upload a file first

Tags: module, drupal-7, drupal-modules, article

Fresh and clean drupal7 install (with lots of necessery modules). If I try to add an article it's allright if I don't use Image. When I add Image - there's a message box: Upload a file first. When I look at server in folder - there is a image file... Any ideas?

Comment: Please clarify what 'lots of necessary modules' means. Can you also provide a screenshot of your content type with the image? Are you on node/add/[node-type]?

Comment: Perhaps one of the many modules you installed is conflicting with the upload, or changed one of the settings on the field? Probably a stupid question, but did you click the upload button next to the field (just trying to cover all bases)?

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned you can see the uploaded file on your server, I am assuming your temp directory and files directory are configured properly with proper permissions.

General Solution:
Eliminate the possibility of other modules interference by disabling modules one by one and trying to upload.
This could be a tedious process depending upon how many modules you have enabled. So start by disabling the most unstable contrib modules first.
However, if disabling one particular module helps you solve the issue and enabling that could replicate your problem, I would suggest reporting the issue in that module's issue queue.

Paste the link to issue queue so we can try to solve the issue.